# How to send metadata with response message with python in bot framework v4

Tags: python, botframework

I want to send information with the response message that is not visible to the user, which I can see in the network tab in the inspect section of the browser.currently I am seeing this information :
[click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W6gt.jpg)

I want to add another key-value pair in this section.

I have tried different solutions, which are working when I test the bot on the emulator but they don't work when I deploy the bot to azure e.g. I have tried the *set activity* property, *trace activity* and I have also tried to set different properties of the activity but none of them are working.

**update:**

I have tried setting the trace activity but it is only displayed in the emulator but not in webchat. here is the code I used.

```py
        trace_activity = Activity(
            label="key",
            name="Trace",
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            type=ActivityTypes.trace,
            value="value",
            value_type="None",
        )
        
        await turn_context.send_activity(trace_activity)
```

also tried the following options but none of them are working:

```py
turn_context.set("key", "value")
```

```py
turn_context.activity.channel_data['key'] = "value"
```

```py
turn_context.activity.conversation.role = "value"
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili I have updated the question.